# Dynamically created table with buttons and requirefieldvalidators c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm creating a table with a a collumn filled with buttons. The button is called "Update" and when I click it everything is working fine. Under this table I have a button "Log" to see the history of the changes made. This hides the first table (panel with table inside) and makes a second panel visible that shows the second table. In this table I have a column with "restore" buttons to restore the data where the status = 0. My problem is here, when i click on this button, it triggers the requiredfieldvalidators of the page. I have used the Validationgroup and the Causesvalidation, but nothing seems to work... Help me please! :)

Here's some code:

Table with update btn that works fine:

```
public void getData()
{
    Provider p = new Provider();
    providers = p.getAllProviders();
    int count = 1;

    //Create a Table
    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.Style["Border-width"] = "5px";
    tbl.Style["Border-style"] = "solid";
    tbl.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    tbl.CellPadding = 5;

    //Header of Table
    TableRow infoRow = new TableRow();

    //Cell of header
    TableCell tch0 = new TableCell();
    tch0.Text = "<b>ProviderID</b>";
    TableCell tch1 = new TableCell();
    tch1.Text = "<b>Name</b>";
    TableCell tch2 = new TableCell();
    tch2.Text = "<b>Phone</b>";
    TableCell tch3 = new TableCell();
    tch3.Text = "<b>Address</b>";
    TableCell tch4 = new TableCell();
    tch4.Text = "<b>Update</b>";

    //Add cells to header
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch0);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch1);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch2);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch3);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch4);

    //Add header to table
    tbl.Rows.Add(infoRow);

    if (providers != null)
    {
        foreach (Provider pr in providers)
        {
            //Create a row
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            //Add lable to evry cell
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            Label pID = new Label();
            tc1.Controls.Add(pID);

            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            Label name = new Label();
            tc2.Controls.Add(name);

            TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
            Label phone = new Label();
            tc3.Controls.Add(phone);

            TableCell tc4 = new TableCell();
            Label address = new Label();
            tc4.Controls.Add(address);

            TableCell tc5 = new TableCell();
            Button updateBtn = new Button();
            updateBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(setUpdate);
            updateBtn.Text = "Update";
            updateBtn.ID = "update" + count;
            updateBtn.ValidationGroup = "updateGrp";
            tc5.Controls.Add(updateBtn);

            //Fill lables
            pID.Text = pr.getProviderID().ToString();
            name.Text = pr.getName();
            phone.Text = pr.getPhone();

            Address a = new Address();
            a.setAddressID(pr.getAddressID());
            a = a.getAddressByID();
            address.Text = a.getStreet() + " " + a.getNumber() + " " + a.getCity() + " " + a.getZipCode() + " " + a.getCountry();

            //Add cells to row
            tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc3);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc4);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc5);

            //Add row to table
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
            count++;
        }
    }
    //Add table to form
    pTableData.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

function of the update btn:

```
public void setUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.ID;
    int idInt = Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(6));

    Provider p = new Provider();
    Address a = new Address();

    p = (Provider)providers[idInt - 1];
    a.setAddressID(p.getAddressID());
    a = a.getAddressByID();

    pUpdate.Visible = true;

    lbl_providerID.Text = p.getProviderID().ToString();
    txt_pUpdate_Name.Text = p.getName();
    txt_pUpdate_Phone.Text = p.getPhone();
    txt_pUpdate_Street.Text = a.getStreet();
    txt_pUpdate_Number.Text = a.getNumber().ToString();
    txt_pUpdate_City.Text = a.getCity();
    txt_pUpdate_ZipCode.Text = a.getZipCode();
    txt_pUpdate_Country.Text = a.getCountry();
}
```

Second table with restore btn:

```
public void getLog()
{
    LogProvider lp = new LogProvider();
    logproviders = lp.getAllLogProviders();
    int count = 1;

    //Create a Table
    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.Style["Border-width"] = "5px";
    tbl.Style["Border-style"] = "solid";
    tbl.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    tbl.CellPadding = 5;

    //Header of Table
    TableRow infoRow = new TableRow();

    //Cell of header
    TableCell tch0 = new TableCell();
    tch0.Text = "<b>LogProviderID</b>";
    TableCell tch1 = new TableCell();
    tch1.Text = "<b>Name</b>";
    TableCell tch2 = new TableCell();
    tch2.Text = "<b>Phone</b>";
    TableCell tch3 = new TableCell();
    tch3.Text = "<b>Address</b>";
    TableCell tch4 = new TableCell();
    tch4.Text = "<b>Status</b>";
    TableCell tch5 = new TableCell();
    tch5.Text = "<b>Type</b>";
    TableCell tch6 = new TableCell();
    tch6.Text = "<b>Updated on</b>";
    TableCell tch7 = new TableCell();
    tch7.Text = "<b>Changed by</b>";
    TableCell tch8 = new TableCell();
    tch8.Text = "<b>Restore</b>";

    //Add cells to header
    //infoRow.Cells.Add(tch0);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch1);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch2);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch3);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch4);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch5);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch6);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch7);
    infoRow.Cells.Add(tch8);

    //Add header to table
    tbl.Rows.Add(infoRow);

    if (providers != null)
    {
        foreach (LogProvider logp in logproviders)
        {
            //Create a row
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            //Add lable to evry cell
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            Label lpID = new Label();
            tc1.Controls.Add(lpID);

            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            Label name = new Label();
            tc2.Controls.Add(name);

            TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
            Label phone = new Label();
            tc3.Controls.Add(phone);

            TableCell tc4 = new TableCell();
            Label address = new Label();
            tc4.Controls.Add(address);

            TableCell tc5 = new TableCell();
            Label status = new Label();
            tc5.Controls.Add(status);

            TableCell tc6 = new TableCell();
            Label type = new Label();
            tc6.Controls.Add(type);

            TableCell tc7 = new TableCell();
            Label updatedOn = new Label();
            tc7.Controls.Add(updatedOn);

            TableCell tc8 = new TableCell();
            Label by = new Label();
            tc8.Controls.Add(by);

            TableCell tc9 = new TableCell();

            //Fill lables
            lpID.Text = logp.getLogProviderID().ToString();
            name.Text = logp.getName();
            phone.Text = logp.getPhone();

            LogAddress la = new LogAddress();
            la.setLogAddressID(logp.getLogProviderID());
            la = la.getLogAddressByID();
            address.Text = la.getStreet() + " " + la.getNumber() + " " + la.getCity() + " " + la.getZipCode() + " " + la.getCountry();

            int stat;
            if (logp.getStatus())
                stat = 1;
            else
                stat = 0;

            status.Text = stat.ToString();
            type.Text = logp.getType();
            updatedOn.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", logp.getUpdateDate());
            by.Text = logp.getUserName();

            if(stat == 0)
            {
                Button restoreBtn = new Button();
                restoreBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(setRestore);
                restoreBtn.Text = "Restore";
                restoreBtn.ID = "restore" + count;
                restoreBtn.ValidationGroup = "restoreGrp";
                tc9.Controls.Add(restoreBtn);
            }

            //Add cells to row
            //tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc3);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc4);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc5);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc6);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc7);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc8);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc9);

            //Add row to table
            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
            count++;
        }
    }
    //Add table to form
    pTableLog.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

Function of the restore btn (doesn't work!!):

```
public void setRestore(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.ID;
    int idInt = Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(7));

    LogProvider lp = new LogProvider();
    Provider p = new Provider();
    LogAddress la = new LogAddress();

    lp = (LogProvider)logproviders[idInt - 1];
    p.setProviderID(lp.getProviderID());
    p = p.getProviderByID();
    la.setLogAddressID(lp.getProviderID());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the logic behind the required field validators in the page. My understandinf is that because of the validators event is not firing ?

If so you can disable the validators just before you call the button click event and enable it later

Comment: The requirefieldvalidators are on 5 textboxes. They are only there to check for required values. If that is ok, than all thoses values are inserted in the db. So those requirefieldvalidators are only there for the insert btn. They Don't have to be triggered when restore is clicked, but they do.